# AWS DynamoDB - The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, aws-cloud9

I have created a Python program on AWS Cloud9 that writes a list to DynamoDB and gives prompts for the user to access the information. When I run the program, I am able to enter the Subject and CatalogNbr, but then it prints an error:

```
Enter the Subject: 
SDEV
Enter the CatalogNbr: 
450
The provided key element does not match the schema
```

The key for the table is the first value called CourseID and they are written as a string:

```
   ['1','SDEV', '450', 'Advanced Programming', '3'],
```

I also set the hash key as a string:

```
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "CourseID", 
                "AttributeType": "S"
            }
        ], 

        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "KeyType": "HASH", 
                "AttributeName": "CourseID"
            }
        ],
```

It seems to match, I think. I've tried changing the values in my defined functions and creating a new table, but I am still getting the same error. The AWS credentials are all in us-east-1. I'm not sure what I need to fix.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import sys
# define DynamoDB variables
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('Courses')
# a list of 10 courses
allCourses = [        
    ['1','SDEV', '450', 'Advanced Programming', '3'],
    ['2','SDEV', '325', 'Detecting Software Vulnerabilities', '3'],
    ['3','CMIS', '102', 'Media and Society', '3'],
    ['4','CMIS', '141', 'Indroductory Programming', '3'],
    ['5','CMIS', '242', 'Intermediate Programming', '3'],
    ['6','CMIS', '102', 'Introduction to Problem Solving and Algorithm Design', '3'],
    ['7','CMIS', '320', 'Relational Database Concepts and Applications', '3'],
    ['8','CHEM', '101', 'Intro to Chemistry', '3'],
    ['9','MATH', '200', 'Calculus 1', '3'],
    ['10','ECON', '101', 'Intro to Economics', '3']
]
    
# for each course in the "allCourses" list
for course in allCourses:
    
    # assign values to variables
    CourseID = course[0]
    Subject = course[1]
    CatalogNbr = course[2]
    Title = course[3]
    NumCredits = course[4]
    
    # put item in table "Courses"
    table.put_item(
        Item={
    'CourseID': CourseID,
    'Subject': Subject,
    'CatalogNbr': CatalogNbr,
    'Title': Title,
    'NumCredits': NumCredits
        }
    )
    
def check_class_info(Subject, CatalogNbr, dynamodb=None): # checks if class info exists
    if not dynamodb:
        dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    
    try:
        response = table.get_item(Key={'Subject': Subject, 'CatalogNbr': CatalogNbr})
        print(get_class_info(Subject, CatalogNbr, Title))
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
        print("Course does not exist. Please try again")
        print(end_navigator())
            
def get_class_info(Subject, CatalogNbr, Title, dynamodb=None): # gets class info from AllCourses
    if not dynamodb:
        dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    try:
        response = table.get_item(Key={'Subject': Subject, 'CatalogNbr': CatalogNbr, 'Title': Title}) 
        print("The title of ", Subject, " ", CatalogNbr, " is ", Title)
        print(end_navigator())
        
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
        print("Cannot retrieve class info. Please try again.")
        print(end_navigator())
        
def end_navigator():
    user_choice = input("Would you like to search for another title? Y or N\n")
    if user_choice == "Y":
        return navigator()
    elif user_choice =="N":
        sys.exit("Thank you for using the Course Title Navigator")
        
    else:
        print("Invalid entry. Please try again.")
        return end_navigator()
            
def navigator():
    
    print("Welcome to the Course Title Navigator\n") # User prompt
    
    print("Enter the Subject: ")
    Subject = str(input())
    
    print("Enter the CatalogNbr: ")
    CatalogNbr = str(input())
    
    check_class_info(Subject, CatalogNbr)
        
    print(get_class_info(Subject, CatalogNbr, Title))
    
    print(end_navigator())
        
print(navigator())
```

And here is the table.

```
    {
    "Table": {
        "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:399520938535:table/Courses", 
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "CourseID", 
                "AttributeType": "S"
            }
        ], 
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0, 
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 150, 
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 150
        }, 
        "TableSizeBytes": 753, 
        "TableName": "Courses", 
        "TableStatus": "ACTIVE", 
        "TableId": "6efba366-56d8-4ad6-86b2-8b14f161c94f", 
        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "KeyType": "HASH", 
                "AttributeName": "CourseID"
            }
        ], 
        "ItemCount": 10, 
        "CreationDateTime": 1614907161.717
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code or (part of the code) that you are using?

Comment: Can you post the full table definition and the query you are performing?  This error usually happens because you are not providing the correct primary key I'm your query.

Comment: `enter the Subject and CatalogNbr` - what is this?

Comment: @samlima I added my code to the post.

Comment: @SethGeoghegan I added the table info using define-table. That is what you were looking for, correct?

Comment: @hoangdv The program allows a user to look up details about the class by entering Subject and CatalogNbr.. The variables and their assigned values are in the beginning of my Python code I added to the post.

Comment: `Key={'Subject': Subject, 'CatalogNbr': CatalogNbr, 'Title': Title})`,  haskey is `CourseID ` not these attr.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @hoangdv mentioned in the comment, the `Key` parameter you are using is not correct. You have to use the Hash key in order to do that (`Key={'CourseID': '3'}`, for example). If you want to get the row based on the `Subject` and the `CatalogNbr`, you have to scan the table and after that look for the results that matches the keys you are looking for. Here is an example of code that could be used to get the `Title` based on ths `Subject` and the `CatalogNbr`:

```
def get_title(Subject, CatalogNbr):
    response = table.scan()
    row = next(item for item in response['Items'] if item['Subject'] == Subject and item['CatalogNbr'] == CatalogNbr)
    title = row['Title']
    print("The title of ", Subject, " ", CatalogNbr, " is ", title)
    return title
```

Another possible solution is change the Hash key, i.e using the attribute `Subject` as Hask Key and `CatalogNbr` as Sorting key. In this case you just have to make sure that this combination will be unique.